# rbind () on a conditional basis

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, rbind

Here's the question. I have a bunch of if statements that create different data frames (A-F) based on the user inputs. In some instances, some of the data frames will be empty, so maybe (A-C) are empty, but (D-F) have information.

I'm trying to create a conditional rbind(), where it combines the rows only if the data frame is not empty.

I'm not quite sure how to go about this? I don't know if I should create a bunch of conditions and use another if statement:

```
cond_a <- nrow(a) != 0
cond_b <- nrow(b) != 0
cond_c <- nrow(c) != 0
cond_d <- nrow(d) != 0
cond_e <- nrow(e) != 0
cond_f <- nrow(f) != 0
```

but then I don't know how to utilize these conditions...

EDIT: To take a step back and better explain: I have one data frame that I split into 6 different data frames by subsetting by a column, so it splits it into 6 data frames (A-G). The column has the letters A-G. These letters A-G in that column change depending on user inputs.

I then have a series of if statements that asks "if A is not empty then perform this aggregation", thereby skipping the df if it has no data in it. The aggregation takes it from 16 to 19 columns. Because the empty df has not been aggregated it still has 19 columns. After I perform these if statements and aggregations, I am left with dfA, dfB, dfC, etc. that have either been aggregated (16 columns) or still empty (19 columns). I then want a piece of code that says "for the df that have been aggregated (16 columns) rbind, if the df has not been aggregated (is empty), then don't perform the rbind.

thanks!

Comment: `rbind` works with empty data.frames. `rbind(data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 1:10), data.frame())`

Comment: the problem is the empty data frames have a different number of columns as a result of the other if statement that creates them, so I'm looking for something that essentially says, if this data frame is empty I'm going to leave it out of the rbind

Comment: I would be curious to see how your empty data.frame looks like

Comment: it's just a df with 19 columns that says " No data available in table", because it is empty is doesn't aggregate to the 16 columns that the non empty ones aggregate to, so I just want to combine the df that have been aggregated, but based on a conditional because depending on the user inputs the number of empty df changes, if that makes sense?

Comment: *"not empty"* is different from *"structured differently"*. `rbind` makes some assumptions about the columns present in the arguments (`dplyr::bind_rows` is a little more allowing). But I think you need to first address the issue of combining data.frames with different fields before realizing that combining empty data.frames (with similar-enough structure) needs no conditioning.

Comment: the data frames I want to combine have all the same fields. I think I may be misexplaining. I will start a step back in what I am doing.  I edited in the question...

Comment: You can certainly do `if (nrow(dfA)>0) df <- rbind(df,dfA)`, but you could also just do `df <- rbind(df, dfA)` regardless of the number of rows in `dfA` (same result!). You don't need to force the use of conditionals.

Comment: but you can't `rbind` if the columns are different lengths I thought, I tried just `rbind` everything and it gives an error because of the diff column lengths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :

1. Create an empty list of the data frames you wish to select.
2. Write a bunch of `if` statements to see which ones contain non-zero zeros
3. Keep adding those names of non-zero DFs to the empty list created in step 1
4. Write an expression which collapses those names to an `rbind` expression
5. Evaluate the expression

Here is the script to do it :

1.Create an Empty list to store the names of dataframes

```
list.df = " "
```

2&3. If statements check if the Data Frame is Non-Zero, add the name to the  list if true

```
if(nrow(df.a) > 0) { 
  list.df=c(list.df,deparse(substitute(df.a)))
 }

if(nrow(df.b) > 0) { 
  list.df=c(list.df,deparse(substitute(df.b)))
 }

if(nrow(df.c) > 0) { 
 list.df=c(list.df,deparse(substitute(df.c)))
 }
```

.... So on from A through G

```
if(nrow(df.g) > 0) { 
 list.df=c(list.df,deparse(substitute(df.g)))
 }
```

4.Formulate the expression

```
list.df = list.df[2:length(list.df)] #remove first element 
expression = paste0("df.combined = rbind(",paste0( list.df, collapse =
','), paste0(")"))
```

5.Evaluate the expression

```
eval(parse(text=expression))
```

`df.combined` will be your final dataset that you are looking for